# Getting Avg, p50, p95 and p99 using hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table which has about 30 million rows like

```
fruit   sold
----------------
apple   5
apple   10
apple   3
orange  2
orange  5
```

For this based on fruit I want to get avg, p50, p90 and p99 like

```
fruit   avg     p50     p95     p99
apple   6       4       4       2
orange  3.5     3       3       4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `percentile()`:

```
select fruit, avg(sold), percentile(sold, 0.5), percentile(sold, 0.95), percentile(sold, 0.99)
from t
group by fruit;
```